# Trigonometric Proof:

Tags: trigonometry, self-learning

**Question:**

If $m\cos\alpha-n\sin\alpha=p$ then prove that $m\sin\alpha+n\cos\alpha=\pm \sqrt{m^2+n^2-p^2}$

**My Efforts:**

$(m\cos\alpha-n\sin\alpha)^{2}=p^2$

$m^2\cos^2\alpha+n^2\sin^2\alpha-2mn\cos\alpha\ \sin\alpha=p^2$

Now i think we need to add something on both side but i can't figure out what to add

Comment: Subtract that from $m^2+n^2$  Is there an obvious way to simplify the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m^2\cos^2\alpha+n^2\sin^2\alpha-2mn\cos\alpha\ \sin\alpha=p^2$$

multiply by $-1$ and add $m^2+n^2$ to both sides :

$$m^2+n^2-m^2\cos^2\alpha-n^2\sin^2\alpha-2mn\cos\alpha\ \sin\alpha=m^2+n^2-p^2$$
$$m^2(1-\cos^2\alpha)+n^2(1-\sin^2\alpha)-2mn\cos\alpha\ \sin\alpha=m^2+n^2-p^2$$
$$m^2(\sin^2\alpha)+n^2(\cos^2\alpha)-2mn\cos\alpha\ \sin\alpha=m^2+n^2-p^2$$
$$(m\sin\alpha+n\cos\alpha)^2=m^2+n^2-p^2$$
$$m\sin\alpha+n\cos\alpha=\pm \sqrt{m^2+n^2-p^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$(m\cos\alpha-n\sin\alpha)^2+(m\sin\alpha+n\cos\alpha)^2=?$$

See also : [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity)

Comment: i guess it will be $2(m^2+n^2)$

Comment: @Freddy, Don't assume when you can calculate easily

Answer (score 1):

From 
$$m^2\cos^2\alpha+n^2\sin^2\alpha-2mn\cos\alpha\ \sin\alpha=p^2$$

we can add $m^2\sin^2\alpha+n^2\cos^2\alpha$ to both sides (to make use of the $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ identity) to achieve

$$m^2(\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha)+n^2(\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha)-2mn\cos\alpha\ \sin\alpha=p^2+m^2\sin^2\alpha+n^2\cos^2\alpha
\\\iff m^2+n^2-p^2=m^2\sin^2\alpha+n^2\cos^2\alpha+2mn\cos\alpha\ \sin\alpha=(m\sin\alpha+n\cos\alpha)^2$$
The result follows.